# Why does Ruby say Closed Stream IOError?

Tags: ruby, stream

I have a problem with my program. It says: "`write': closed stream (IOError)".

```
def backup(dir, file, time="")
    fullpath = "#{dir}/#{file}"
    #puts fullpath

        @f.puts "BKP_DATE: #{$date}"
        @f.puts "BKP_DIRECTORY: #{dir}"
        @f.puts "M_TIME: #{time}"
        @f.puts "BKP_FILE: #{file}"


        IO.readlines(fullpath).each do |line|

            @f.puts line
        end
        @f.close()

end
```

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: Maybe you are calling `backup` two times in a row without reopening the file `@f`?

Comment: In my program i've call two times the function backup.

if self.backup(base, f, temps) != false
    puts self.backup(base, f, temps)
end

He is call in the if and the puts.

Works well if i comment the if...

Can we pause Ruby Script ? (5 seconds for exemple).

Thanks you for your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So your program is essentially like this:

```
f = File.open("foo.dat", "w")

f.puts "BKP_DATE: "
...
IO.readlines(fullpath).each do |line|
    f.puts line
end
f.close
f.puts "BKP_DATE: "
...
IO.readlines(fullpath).each do |line|
    f.puts line
end
f.close
```

You tried to `close` the same `File` object twice.

I don't know the whole structure of your program, but perhaps you should instantiate the `File` object inside your `backup` method.  And this is how you should write it in Ruby (:

```
File.open("foo.dat", "w") {|f|
    f.puts "BKP_DATE: "
    IO.readlines(fullpath).each do |line|
        f.puts line
    end
} # f is automatically closed here
```

If you really need to open the file outside your `backup` method, I think what you need at the end of `bakcup` is `@f.flush` rather than `@f.close`.  This would be an acceptable solution for you provided that you don't open hundreds of files in your script.

As for pausing, try `sleep 5.0`

- http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/sleep

Comment: @Quentin I think I understood your explanation.  But do you mean you still have other problems?

Comment: Yes, i've other problem here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21630273/how-can-i-wait-for-the-write-of-a-file?noredirect=1#comment32686662_21630273

Comment: 'You tried to close the same File object twice.', solved it for me.