# How can I wait for the write of a file?

Tags: ruby, file, wait

When I execute this program, it works well but the verification returns false. If I re-execute it, the verification works.

`fullpath` is the directory of the backup, and `refpath` is the path to the original files:

```
if (fullpath.include?(refpath) && refpath.empty? == false && fullpath.empty? == false)
  diffpath= "#{fullpath} #{refpath}"
  puts diffpath
  sortie = IO.popen("diff -Bb #{diffpath}").readlines #(fullpath backup_dir)
  #puts fullpath
  if sortie.empty?

    puts "Les fichiers -#{f} sont identiques."

  else
    puts "Modification : [#{refpath}] \n [#{fullpath}] "
  end
end
```

The main program is:

```
require "modif.rb"
require "testdate.rb"
require "restore_data.rb"

#Pour la sauvegarde des fichiers
puts "__________SAUVEGARDE__________"

#Pour la restauration des fichiers :
puts "__________RESTAURATION__________"

#Vérification de l'intégrité des fichiers restaurés.
puts "__________VERIFICATION__________"
sleep(5.0)
v = Verif.new
v.do_verif(outdir)
```

When I open the directory where the files are restored, the files are not completely written.

Before calling the verification, I call save, backup and verification.

The `sleep` doesn't work. The process is completely paused and won't write the missing files.

Comment: What functions do save / restore use to write the files?

Comment: I cleaned up your question to (hopefully) make it more understandable. Looking at your code, I don't see any attempt to write a file. `IO.popen("diff -Bb #{diffpath}").readlines` could be more easily done using `%x` or backticks. Also, you don't need to use ".rb" extensions for files you `require`. Ruby automatically adds the ".rb" extension if it can't find the file without it.

Comment: This may be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701103/understanding-ruby-and-os-i-o-buffering Also, you probably want to translate your comments into english as not everyone speaks french here ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many gigabytes does your original file have in size?  I suspect if `sleep 5.0` isn't really meaningful and the root cause is something else.  Or do you use a slow USB flash memory as the backup directory?

If you are sure that you need to wait for the writing process to complete, perhaps you can do polling on `mtime` of the backup file:

```
finished = false
30.times { # deadline of 30*10 == 300 seconds
  if 5 < (File.mtime(fullpath) - Time.now).abs
    # the backup process had done its job
    finished = true
    break
  end
  sleep 10
}

if finished
  v = Verif.new
...
```

When the backup process is in the middle of writing into the output file, `File.mtime(fullpath)` should be within 2 seconds from `Time.now` Be careful of the FAT filesystem with 2 seconds time resolution.  I also used `abs` because some backup programs modify `mtime` value as they want.

Answer (score 1):

This hasn't been tested, but is more how I'd write the first part:

```
if ((fullpath != '') && fullpath[refpath] && (refpath != ''))
  sortie = `diff -Bb #{ fullpath } #{ refpath }`
  if sortie == ''
    puts "Les fichiers -#{ f } sont identiques."
  else
    puts "Modification : [#{ refpath }] \n [#{ fullpath }] "
  end
end
```

In general you can simplify your tests. While it's nice that Ruby has the `empty?` method to see if something has content, it's more obvious if you use `== ''` or `!= ''`.

Using `fullpath[refpath]` will return a matching string or `nil`, so you have a "truthy/falsey" response there, with less code noise.

Use backticks or `%x` to get the output of your "diff" instead of using `popen` with `readlines`.

In general, your code looked like you're coming from Java. Ruby has a very elegant syntax and writing style so take advantage of it.

Comment: The file is create but is void and i need the function save finishes write all the files before the main program continues.